# trigger que al eliminar un registro de una tabla padre y el mismo está relacionado con un registro

Tags: mysql, trigger

¿**que estructura debería de llevar un `trigger`** para que al eliminar un registro de una tabla padre y el mismo está relacionado con un registro en una tabla hija, se deberá detener el `trigger` y enviar un mensaje que dicha acción no es posible realizar?

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `comp01`.`ELiminar***` 
 AFTER INSERT ON `comp01`.`<ft_inv_slvta>`
    BEGIN
      DELETE FROM comp01.ft_inv_slvta WHERE codref = '***'
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Quieres que obligatoriamente sea con TRIGGER? es más fácil, si lo haces con una llave foránea  ON DELETE RESTRICT, con esto no te dejara eliminar nodos de la tabla padre, que tengan registros en la tabla hija. Cabe mencionar que la llave foránea se registra en la tabla hija

Answer (score 0):

Primero debes de hacer un select para saber si el registro que estas eliminando tiene registros en la tabla hija

```
DECLARE hijos INT(11) DEFAULT 0;
SELECT count(*) INTO hijos from tablahijo where idPadre = OLD.idPadre;
```

Después comparas y si tienes hijos, entonces cancelas el delete

```
if (hijos > 0) THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'DELETE canceled'; 
END iF;
```

No conozco la estructura de tus tablas así que aquí te dejo la que utilice yo

```
CREATE TABLE tablahijo (
  idHijo int(255) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  idPadre varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (idHijo)
);
CREATE TABLE tablapadre (
  idPadre int(255) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (idPadre)
);

INSERT INTO ejercicio.tablahijo (idHijo,idPadre) VALUES (1, '1'),(2, '2');
INSERT INTO ejercicio.tablapadre (idPadre) VALUES (1),(2),(3);


CREATE  TRIGGER eliminar BEFORE DELETE ON tablapadre FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
DECLARE hijos INT(11) DEFAULT 0;
SELECT count(*) INTO hijos from tablahijo where idPadre = OLD.idPadre;
if (hijos > 0) THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'DELETE canceled'; 
END iF;
END;;
```

Espero y te sirva